# Web search for file with known name - to download

Tags: google-search

I know a file is available somewhere on the internet for download whose exact name I know, e.g. *abc-def-ghi.pdf*. If I enter the filename into the Google search box, Google does not find it.

I found the file by searching Google for text which is contained in the file. From this Google search, I can download the file. Also, later I can download the file again just by entering the URL found by Google search.

How though can I use Google to search for web pages where this file is available for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this searchterm helps you: `allinurl:  "abc-def-ghi.pdf" filetype:pdf`.
You should also check out Googles advanced search: https://www.google.com/advanced_search

Answer (score 0):

A weird solution worked for me: enter a wrong filename (specifically, I removed the dot before the file extension; removing the entire file extension didn't help in all cases) ***or*** change the search language. Then Google shows images from revelant webpages.

Google's behavior is weird:

- The same webpages may not appear among the usual search results. In some cases, it says "0 search results", followed by those images.
- Changing the search language can make irrelevant results appear but make those images disappear.
- Some of those images don't appear in Google image search.